# Custom golang sql.NullString Stringer Interface

Tags: go

I want to override the Stringer interface for all instances sql.NullString so that the output of an instance is `instance.String` rather than `{ instance.String, instance.Valid }`.

The normal way of doing this is to provide a Stringer interface.
With sql.NullString a Stringer interface method fails to compile as there is already a String field.

The workaround is to just use `instance.String` everywhere.

```
type NullString sql.NullString

// this fails to compile as sql.NullString has a field named String  
func (x *NullString) String() string {
    if !x.Valid {
        x.String = ""
    }
    return x.String
}
```

How can a Stinger interface be created if a struct already, like sql.NullString, has a String field?

Comment: Note: `type NullString sql.NullString` "loses" the `Scan` and `Value` methods, therefore an instance of *your* NullString will lose its purpose.

Comment: "I want to override the Stringer interface for all instances sql.NullString" makes no sense as you cannot do this in Go. You cannot override. Let go of OOP terms which make no sense in Go.

Comment: @Volker Happy to reword the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
import "database/sql/driver"

type NullString struct { ns sql.NullString }

func (s *NullString) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    return s.ns.Scan(value)
}

func (s NullString) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return s.ns.Value()
}

func (s NullString) String() string {
    return s.ns.String
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct - but extending `sql.Nullstring` avoids the need to redefine all existing and future (and non-overwritten) methods.

Comment: @chris_f How would you extend sql.NullString ?

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison Go does not support type extensions, so my guess is that chris_f is referring to *embedding* the type just like it's demonstrated in Sarath's answer.

Comment: As @mkopriva points out: you cannot extend an existing type or overwrite its methods such that the change shows up everywhere in a transparent manner.
Providing a new type that embeds the `sql.NullString` anonymously is the only relief that I'm aware of. There you can add and/or overwrite methods as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend extending the sql.NullString and overriding or adding methods to the extended type.

```
// NS extends sql null string
type NS struct{ sql.NullString }

func (s NS) String() string {
    return s.NullString.String
}
```

NS will have the methods of sql.NullString aswell as the methods that are aded to NS itself as well.

Here is a sample usage in [playgorund](https://play.golang.org/p/o9NBxfQ_IcM)